# How to mount webdav disk from chrome extention

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome no longer supports NPAPI, so I need to rewrite my java-applet, e.g. as chrome extension.

Chrome community advices [JavaScript API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) as alternative for access to OS features (see [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation))

Could you please point me, which exactly API allows to mount webdav disk?

Answer (score 1):

OS access in Chrome apps/extensions is severely limited for security reasons so I think you'd be better off transforming your existing java code into a standalone application which will run in background and communicate with your Chrome extension via [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly need to do more research.

There is no feature parity between NPAPI and JS APIs. What's [listed in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) is the extent of JS API capabilities, and it's mostly sandboxed from real OS environment.

To replicate NPAPI capabilities, the closest alternative is (as wOxxOm's answer suggests) [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). Note that it is mentioned in the deprecation notice you quote. If you need to mount something on the host OS, that's your only option.

---

[Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/) have [a different set of APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) available for them, which usually are less restricted in terms of sandboxing. For instance, r/w access to user-specified portions of host OS filesystem is possible.

Lastly, for the sake of completeness, there is a [very specific `fileSystemProvider` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider) **targeting ChromeOS only** that allows you to do exactly that, provide a mountable filesystem from a Chrome App.

---

All that said, if you don'y need to present the WebDAV disk to the host OS but just manipulate some files within the extension, there are pure-JS implementations of WebDAV (not using any platform-specific APIs). It all depends on what you intend to do with the filesystem.